# jquery .css() won't set multiple properties programmatically

Tags: jquery, css

This works:

```
var property1 = "width";

$('.button1').on("click", function(){
    $('.greenbox').css(property1, "200px");
});
```

But this doesn't:

```
var property1 = "width";
var property2 = "border-top";

$('.button2').on("click", function(){
    $('.greenbox').css({
        property1: "50px",
        property2: "50px"
    });
});
```

Why? And what's the easiest, fastest, slickest. most cross-browserest way to set an unknown quantity of multiple (unknown) properties? I know the *values*, I just don't know the *properties*. :)

http://jsfiddle.net/4KwXa/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Javascript when constructing an object you can only define keys as strings.. meaning the values in `property1` and `property2` will not be passed.. instead the strings 'property1' and 'property2' will be passed..

To overcome this, create the object in advanced, then pass it whole: ([working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4KwXa/3/))

```
var cssObj = {};
cssObj[property1] = '50px';
cssObj[property2] = '50px';
$('.greenbox').css(cssObj);
```

**Edit:**

I couldn't find it in the docs to back me up but the case is this:

When you use the following notation: `{key1:value1, key2:value2}` javascript parses the keys as names, and even though there's a variable with the same name defined javascript is not passing the value but only the name - this is how it was built - the keys cannot be passed as variables.

Using `cssObj[peroperty1]` works because we're basically treating the object as an associative array - and assigning a key as a variable is allowed in this way.

Comment: Thanks. There's something fundamental here I'm trying to grasp. Why is  it that when the object is created inside the function call, the keys don't refer to variables, just themselves, but when the object is created externally and then passed in, the variables references are passed in?

Answer (score 1):

The reason it's not working is because you're setting the object passed's `property1` and `property2` instead of the actual value of `property1` and `property2`, etc. It's just how JavaScript interprets the objects.

A solution to this problem is to just use arrays.

```
var properties = ['width', 'border-top'];

$('.button2').on('click', function() {
    for(var i = 0; i < properties.length; i++)
        $('.greenbox').css(properties[i], '50px');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're creating an object with the literal value "property1" as the key. If you want to take the approach you're attempting, try this:

```
var property1 = "width";
var property2 = "border-top";

var styles = {};
styles[property1] = "50px";
styles[property2] = "50px";

$('.button2').on("click", function(){
    $('.greenbox').css(styles);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not specifying the property names correctly. When you say `property1: '50px'`, you're actually setting the property called "property1" to 50px.

http://jsfiddle.net/4KwXa/1/

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is wrong. To get your code to work correctly.

```
cssObj.css("property1", "50px").css("property2", "50px")
```

some of the above answers may achieve what you are trying to do more elegantly.

Comment: yah, figured that one :) Actually this won't work either with the properties in quotes as you have it.

Comment: spotted. Too much rushing - property 1 and 2 are variables

Answer (score 0):

In the way you are defining key for key:'values' of object. The key itself can't be a variable.

For that you need this notation:

```
var obj[variable]='value';
```

do what i have **done here...**
http://jsfiddle.net/techsin/4KwXa/4/

you need to do something like this:

```
var props={};
    props[property1]= "50px";
    props[property2]= "50px";
```